# Positioning of child nodes (forest, beamer)

Tags: tikz-pgf, forest, trees

I already found [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83972/tikz-tree-and-position-of-single-leaf-in-binary-tree) post on how to do the thing I want to achieve, but this uses tikz and I'm using the forest package. Is forest based on tikz? How can I do this with forest?

My Problem is I have a tree and want to remove one leaf. But after that it should not change the arrangement of the other nodes, the structure should stay the same.

Example:

```
        X
       / \
      /   \
     /     \
    Y       Z
```

Remove Y

```
        X
         \
          \
           \
            Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node {X}
    child { node {} edge from parent[draw=none]}
    child { node {Z}}
;
    \end{tikzpicture}        
\end{document}
```

with `forest`:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={s sep=11mm}
[X  [,phantom]
    [ Z]
]
    \end{forest} 
\end{document}
```

or considering yours and cfr's comments:

```
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={s sep=11mm}
[X  [\phantom{Y}, no edge, draw=none]
    [ Z]
]
    \end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but a `[,phantom]` node does not create a invisible node, more something like a non existing node. I just achieved what I wanted with `[,no edge, opacity=0]`. Thanks anyway

Comment: sufficient is `no edge` :-)

Comment: Ah true, I used node borders in my own example (not in the question) so I had to set the opacity of that to 0 too

Comment: @IanFako `[\phantom{Y}, no edge, draw=none, ...` if you don't want the calculations to change at all.